# issue importing a function

Tags: python, function, import

im trying to import a simple print function from my Funcs but it keeps giving me a invalid syntax her
Func1(): <

heres my Funcs.py file

```
def Func1():
    print('test')
```

and heres my main.py file

```
import Funcs

Func1():
```

console

```
    Func1():
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Call a function as ``Func1()``, not ``Func1():``.

Comment: I don't think you need the : after it is imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your function without `:`

```
import Funcs
Funcs.Func1()
```

or

```
from Funcs import Func1
Func1()
```

or

```
from Funcs import *
Func1()
```

Comment: i tried it and now it tells me                                                                                                 
  name 'Func1' is not defined

Comment: never mind i used from Func import Func1 and it worked

Comment: there is your full answer